# Read matching rules from a file. Pattern contained in a variable

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to read a matching pattern from a config file using Config::INifiles.
I.e. everything is contained in variables.

Matching works fine:

```
my $user = "CN=vpn,ou=test";
my $pattern = 'CN=(.*),ou=test';

if ($user =~ /$pattern/) {
    print "match\n";
    print $1;
};
```

But now I would also like to access the first match using `$1`, which I would also like to read from the config file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
my $user = "CN=vpn,ou=test";
my $pattern = 'CN=(.*),ou=test';
my $m = "\\$1";

if ($user =~ /$pattern/) {
    print "match\n";
    print $m;
};
```

Comment: What are you going to do with that `$1`? Can you provide more context and a sample config?

Comment: @melpomene actually I have a 2fa auth system that can return e.g. the group memberships of a user as DN. A perl freeradius plugin is supposed to forward not the complete DN but a substring of the DN as RADIUS attributes to a VPN server. And of course, yes, this should be super flexible.  So the $1 should be written to a radius attribute.

Comment: Why are you declaring `$m` outside of the block it is used in? And if you're using it later, then give it a better name.

Comment: @shawnhcorey this code is an example! ``$m`` is actually read from a config file and would have another name.

Comment: @cornelinux That's called a symbolic reference and is not PBP (Perl Best Practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this might help you:

```
my $user = 'CN=vpn,ou=test';
my $pattern = 'CN=(.*),ou=test';
my $m = 1; # number of capturing group

if (my @c = $user =~ /$pattern/) {
    print "match\n";
    print $c[$m-1];
};
```

Comment: This is interesting and does the job. I was however hoping for a more flexible solution in the long run. I even would like to add even static parts. maybe like ``$1-static-suffix``. I was experimenting with ``$user =~ s/$pattern/$1some static part/`` but also could not get this as strings from a config file.

Comment: @cornelinux, Thank you for your interest, but it looks like you're changing your requirements. You asked the question and received several answers. And now you want something different. Do you really know what you need? If yes, does your question reflect your needs?

Comment: You are right. My initially question was my main pain. And you are right. I added a nice-to-have requirement, which I did not mention in the first place, because I though it would be to complicated and because it is a nice to have thingy. If I need more than one match your answer is definitvely the way to go. So for other readers of the thread I will mark this as answer. :-) (If I ever figure out how to solve my nice-to-have wish I will add this here, too)

Answer (score 0):

You can view `$m` as Perl code to be executed, or as a template. The latter is the much better approach. You can use String::Substitution's `interpolate_match_vars` as your template processor.

```
use String::Substitution qw( interpolate_match_vars last_match_vars );

my $interpolated = interpolate_match_vars($m, last_match_vars());
```

Comment: Thx. I first need to process and understand this... :-)

Comment: This perl module does not seem to be packed for ubuntu. Makes it harder to use the code in my project.